# C# Socket BeginReceive / EndReceive capturing multiple messages

Tags: c#, sockets

Problem:

When I do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    SendMessage( sometSocket, i.ToString());
    Thread.Sleep(250); // works with this, doesn't work without
}
```

With or without the sleep the server logs sending of separate messages. However without the sleep the client ends up receiving multiple messages in single OnDataReceived so the client will receive messages like:

0,
1,
2,
34,
5,
678, 
9 ....

**Server sending Code:**

```
private void SendMessage(Socket socket, string message)
{
    logger.Info("SendMessage: Preparing to send message:" + message);            

    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    if (socket == null) return;
    if (!socket.Connected) return;

    logger.Info("SendMessage: Sending message to non " +
                "null and connected socket with ip:" + socket.RemoteEndPoint);

    // Record this message so unit testing can very this works.

    socket.Send(byteData);
}
```

**Client receiving code:**

```
private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    logger.Info("OnDataReceived: Data received.");

    try
    {
        SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
        int iRx = theSockId.Socket.EndReceive(asyn);
        char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
        System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.DataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
        System.String szData = new System.String(chars);

        logger.Info("OnDataReceived: Received message:" + szData);

        InvokeMessageReceived(new SocketMessageEventArgs(szData));

        WaitForData();  // .....
```

**Socket Packet:**

```
public class SocketPacket
{
    private Socket _socket;
    private readonly int _clientNumber;
    private byte[] _dataBuffer = new byte[1024]; ....
```

*My hunch is it's something to do with the buffer size or its just the between the OnDataReceived and EndReceive we're getting multiple messages.*

**Update: It turns out when I put a Thread.Sleep at the start of OnDataReceived it gets every message. Is the only solution to this wrapping my message in a prefix of length and an string to signify the end?**

Comment: Unrelated: The mixing of ASCII encoder and UTF8 decoder looks odd. It'll work but still...

Comment: Yeah, please use UTF8, even if you expect only ASCII data. MSDN claims that the ASCII en/decoder should be considered obsolete and the UTF8 one is faster.

Comment: The ASCII encoder does have its place.  Some servers will freak out if they receive characters outside ASCII's range.  But in general, yeah -- servers should expect UTF-8, and the ASCII decoder should die.

Comment: @cHao: If the server doesn’t accept characters outside ASCII, then the software probably shouldn’t try to send them. Using the ASCII Encoder would only serve to mask a bug.

Comment: @Timwi: Unless i can change the code on the server, i don't care whether i'm covering up a bug on their end -- i just want stuff to work.  And using the encoding they expect is the most appropriate way of doing that, regardless of what MS wants to call obsolete.

Comment: @cHao: Looks like we’re talking about two different things. I’m not talking about a case where the server has a bug. I’m talking about a case where sending non-ASCII bytes *violates the protocol*. In that case, doing so is *your* bug, not the server’s. If the server fails on non-ASCII bytes *even though the protocol allows it*, then of course the server is the one that has a bug, but if you try to work around it by using only ASCII and then fail to do so, then you **both** have a bug. In both cases, using the ASCII encoding masks your bug.

Comment: @Timwi: If the server is expecting ASCII, then sending non-ASCII may be a violation of the protocol.  Whether it causes problems is irrelevant -- if the protocol specifies ASCII, then the most appropriate encoding to use in such a case is the ASCII encoding.  And even if it doesn't, ASCII at least makes things work.

Comment: @cHao: If the protocol specifies ASCII, then your application should not generate non-ASCII protocol data at all, even before encoding it. If it generates such data, it has a bug. If you use the ASCII encoding because you think it might generate such data, then you are masking the bug.

Comment: @Timwi: If i use the ASCII encoding, it *won't* generate such data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is **expected behaviour.** A TCP socket represents a linear stream of bytes, *not* a sequence of well-delimited “packets”. You must not assume that the data you receive is chunked the same way it was when it was sent.

Notice that this has **two** consequences:

1. Two messages may get merged into a single callback call. (You noticed this one.)
2. A single message may get split up (at any point) into two separate callback calls.

Your code *must* be written to handle both of these cases, otherwise it has a bug.

Comment: Nitpick: A *TCP* socket represents a linear stream of bytes.  UDP sockets are message-oriented, and the data received is chunked together the same way it was sent.

Comment: great! this basically clarifies everything and makes sense why I am getting this behavior. thanks both CHao and Timiwi. 

I will think about how UDP affects my overall architecture vs. wrapping a message in something to signify its a complete message.

Comment: When you think about UDP vs a message protocol, also consider what you'll do if a message hasn't been completely read in yet.  In TCP, if you're not careful, you'll either read in part of a message or block waiting for the rest (which, if it was lost in transit, could take a while to arrive).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to abandon Tcp because it is stream oriented.

You can fix the problems that you are having by implementing message framing.

See

http://blogs.msdn.com/malarch/archive/2006/06/26/647993.aspx

also:

http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Comment: You'd need to make sure that the code that reads messages processes exactly one message at a time (not two, not part of one).  And you better pray the messages are always framed correctly, or that there's some kind of protocol for restoring the stream to a usable state.

Answer (score -2):

TCP sockets don't always send data right away -- in order to minimize network traffic, TCP/IP implementations will often buffer the data for a bit and send it when it sees there's a lull (or when the buffer's full).

If you want to ensure that the messages are processed one by one, you'll need to either set `socket.NoDelay = true` (which might not help much, since data received may still be bunched up together in the receive buffer), implement some protocol to separate messages in the stream (like prefixing each message with its length, or perhaps using CR/LF to separate them), or use a message-oriented protocol like SCTP (which might not be supported without additional software) or UDP (if you can deal with losing messages).

Comment: attempted the socket.NoDelay = true to no avail. 

by looking at my server logs it definitely is sending the messages one by one.

its looking more and more likely I'll need something to wrap the messages to separate them :(

Comment: Yeah...TCP was made for stream-oriented stuff.  You'll need some way to tell when a message starts and ends.  I'd actually recommend UDP or SCTP if you can use them, as a malformed message in TCP can cause corruption of the whole stream.  UDP, on the other hand, is harder to mess up like that -- each message is discrete, and you don't need to worry about whether the length was set correctly.

Comment: -1 for suggesting UDP over TCP, UDP is only a option if it's allowed to loose packages, and if you don't want that you'll end up implementing a TCP-like system on your UDP protocol. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Comment: @Stormenet: UDP is an option if you can deal with dropped packets (which, over a LAN, is kinda rare).  If you can't, then your options are limited anyway.  TCP wasn't built for messages; it considers incoming data as a bunch of bytes, and in order to separate those bytes into messages, you're going to need to implement some protocol for separating them.  Basically, you'd be inventing UDP over TCP, which isn't any better than the reverse IMO.  The only way you're gonna get both without reinventing one or the other is SCTP (which i've added), but AFAIK Windows doesn't support it natively yet.

Comment: @cHao, even if it is rare, the rare times it will happen you will spend hours looking why that in those rare occasion your application crashes for who knows what reason. Also UDP also is a stream of bytes you the only reason one would choos UDP is that speed is important and the risk of loosing packages won't bring down your app.

Comment: @Stormenet: UDP is not a "stream of bytes" in anywhere near the same way as TCP is. You send one message in UDP, and the other end sees one message.  (Perhaps zero messages, but that's what ACKs and timeouts are for.)  Not a stream, not two messages, not part of a message.  You send one in TCP, and...well, then you have the problems that led to this question. TCP was not built for messages; every aspect of its design conspires to *hide* the boundaries between packets behind a stream of bytes. Why start with a protocol that was *designed* to do the very things that are causing you problems?

Comment: @cHao, you still have a limit on how big your UDP message can be, when you reach that you'll have to chunk up your own data...

Comment: @Stormenet: The maximum size of a UDP datagram is over 65000 bytes.  The more practical limit (Ethernet MTU) is about 1500, and the most severe limit (minimum MTU for IPv4) is about 560, but even that is more than big enough for a useful message (particularly the tiny ones being sent in the question).  If you have a "message" bigger than 512 bytes or so, then what you have more than likely isn't a message at all -- it's a document, and would likely be more useful as a stream of bytes anyway.