# How can I avoid the merging of message from the same socket

Tags: c#, sockets

similar question:
[C# Socket BeginReceive / EndReceive capturing multiple messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504654/c-sharp-socket-beginreceive-endreceive-capturing-multiple-messages)

I am currently managing the communication between a website and a winform application, which is done by websocket created that way:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
SocketType.Stream, 
ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

If the emmitter send two messages A([TagBeginMessage:lengthMessageA] aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [EndMessage]) and B([TagBeginMessage: lengthMessageB] bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb [EndMessage]), I expect that the receiver will get

*[TagBeginMessage:lengthMessageA] aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [EndMessage][TagBeginMessage: lengthMessageB] bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb [EndMessage]*

or

*[TagBeginMessage: lengthMessageB] bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb [EndMessage][TagBeginMessage:lengthMessageA] aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [EndMessage]*

This is indeed the case for the vast majority of message, however the necessary asynchronous nature of the reception sometimes causes a bug when the message A is quite long and the message B quite short, in which the receiver get this:

*[TagBeginMessage:lengthMessageA] aaaaaaaaaa[TagBeginMessageB: lengthMessageB] bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb [EndMessage]aaaaaa [EndMessageA]*

This can still be parsed, although it required unique ending for each message. However, while I didn't see it, I am afraid that this means that the following case is also possible (due to the fact that the socket send their data by packet):

*[TagBeginMessage:lengthMessageA] aaaaa[TagBeginMessageB: lengthMessageB] bbbbbbaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbb [EndMessage]aaaaaa [EndMessageA]*

This is unparseable. Adding a length (as suggested in http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html) to the beginning of the message indicates the problem but doesn't solve it. What can I do to avoid this?

My current solution are:

- Send small message. Not elegant but should work.
- Send very smallmessage to signal that the buffer of the socket is empty.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are sending data on the same connection from multiple threads simultaneously. That's fine, but if you do that, make sure you lock the connection to the current thread for the duration of sending out a logical package (length + data) - that way you will receive a complete packet (sent from one thread) before receiving anything that a different thread sent.

Under TCP/IP, packages are guaranteed to arrive in the same order that they were sent, but if you send, say, half a logical package (length + data) from one thread then half a package from another, then there is no way for the protocol layer or the receiving end to know that.

Comment: Good point about multiple threads, but since he never actually saw the unparsable example then I assume that isn't actually happening..

Comment: The bug is really rare. I saw it once and didn't manage to reproduce it, so me not seeing it doesn't mean it can't happen. I do work on multiple threads, but I think that the sendings of the message is synchronous. I will make sure of it by queuing the message.

Answer (score 2):

You have already linked to Stephen Cleary's blog so you know that tcp requires you to do some form of message framing. [Here is the another one of Cleary's posts that describe your problem.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)

In short you must frame your tcp messages. You should also never see your final, unparsable, example. Tcp will send all of your data in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert with sockets, but i have some experience. What you could do is split the data thats being sent. Say you have a very long string that has the following: "AAAAAAAABBBBBBCCCCDDDDDEEE". What you could do is instead of sending the entire string through the socket at once you could send all the A characters then the B then the C and then the D etc. Right before the user recieves the message you could merge all the characters together. Thats just an idea.